# Hadoop Hbase workflow

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm still relatively new to hadoop, and I've been learning a bit about it by doing some sample exercises, but I had a question about how it is used in practice. A lot of the applications seem to be geared toward batch processing (such as logfile data), but I'm not sure how hbase fits in here?

Is it common to store the logfile data in hbase and then process and output it to some other storage format? Is it more common to just pass the raw logfiles into hadoop and then store the output in hbase? I guess my real question here is typically hbase used as an input or output of hadoop, or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HBase is for use wherever you need random, low latency access to the data, whereas most of the rest of the Hadoop ecosystem is batch oriented as you mention.

To use your log parsing example, you can process log files stored in HDFS via MapReduce, but what then?  Presumably you want to see traffic patterns over time (minutes, hours, days, whatever).  If you store the results in HBase with the timestamp as the row key, then you can efficiently query a particular date range (for example, "Show me all of the data from last week.")  HBase will return that much more quickly than classic MapReduce, because it doesnt need to scan through all of the data from last month, last year, etc., whereas MapReduce would.

Comment: that makes sense. Are there cases where you might want to store the input data in hbase?

Comment: Sure- if you have multiple machines writing for instance, HBase is quite good about handling that.  And if you are running MapReduce jobs to process your logs, those jobs will be more efficient if they run both the Mappers and the Reducers (input and output) on the HBase RegionServers, because then the data is less likely to need to be copied over the network to the target storage node.

Answer (score 2):

Flume is how a lot of people have hooked up their log files to do real-time processing of that data as it is produced.  You can create a source from each log file and have a sync to your HBase instance

Also look at OpenTSDB, as they have a very nice system for storing cluster metrics on top of HBase.  You might be able to reuse some of their infrastructure to do your log analytics.